# How to show last six months data(one row for each month) in MDX query based on selected month filter in Power BI report?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, mdx

I have created a cube with one fact table and 5 dimension which includes one Date dimension. Hierarchy of date dimension is Year -> Quater -> Month. Here I want to select the last six months data from selected month using mdx query. The output should be Month (Row Level) and Measures on Column level.

Thought of creating a dynamic named set but power BI doesn't consume named sets.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do it in MDX either using a disconnected date dimension or any idea in Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the sample below

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on 0
,
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[4].lag(6):
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[4] 
on 1 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result[image]

Comment: How to do it in calculated measure in ssas?

Comment: @user11600560 a calculated measure will perform an aggregate on them and result a single value. If you want breakup either use Sets or handle it in the select query.

Comment: Power BI live connection doesn't support named sets and we can't write select query as well in power bi.